# Creating a new column with two unique conditions in pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Trying to figure out something complex with pandas - I have this sample dataframe:

```
Date             Value      Diff
4/2/2019 17:00   864        57      
4/2/2019 17:15   864        0
4/2/2019 17:30   864        0
4/2/2019 17:45   864        0
4/2/2019 18:00   864        0
...
5/2/2019 07:00   864        0
5/2/2019 07:15   864        0
5/2/2019 07:30   864        0
5/2/2019 07:45   864        0
5/2/2019 08:00   864        0
5/2/2019 08:15   864        0
5/2/2019 08:30   1564       700
5/2/2019 08:45   1784       223
5/2/2019 09:00   1904       120
5/2/2019 09:15   2095       191
5/2/2019 09:30   2095       183
5/2/2019 09:45   2095       85
5/2/2019 10:00   2095       58
5/2/2019 10:15   2095       134
5/2/2019 10:30   2555       78
5/2/2019 10:45   2678       123
5/2/2019 11:00   2777       99
```

The expected dataframe is this:

```
Date             Value      Diff      NewCol1
4/2/2019 17:00   864        57        57
4/2/2019 17:15   864        0         63.63
4/2/2019 17:30   864        0         63.63
4/2/2019 17:45   864        0         63.63
4/2/2019 18:00   864        0         63.63
...
5/2/2019 07:00   864        0         63.63
5/2/2019 07:15   864        0         63.63
5/2/2019 07:30   864        0         63.63
5/2/2019 07:45   864        0         63.63
5/2/2019 08:00   864        0         63.63
5/2/2019 08:15   864        0         63.63
5/2/2019 08:30   1564       700       63.63
5/2/2019 08:45   1784       223       223
5/2/2019 09:00   1904       120       120
5/2/2019 09:15   2095       191       191
5/2/2019 09:30   2095       183       183
5/2/2019 09:45   2095       85        85
5/2/2019 10:00   2095       58        58
5/2/2019 10:15   2095       134       134
5/2/2019 10:30   2555       78        78
5/2/2019 10:45   2678       123       123
5/2/2019 11:00   2777       99        99
...
```

There are two conditions to create the `NewCol1`,

1. When `Value` is repeated, if `Diff` is 0, and only between **time range from 07:00 to 18:00**, count the number of 0 + 1 and the difference of the `Value` and divide it (in this example, `(1564 - 864) / 11`). Take note that the `+ 1` is to account the row after the last `0`, which is the row at `08:30` and this sort of occurrence will always happen consecutively such as this example patern (example `4/2/2019 17:15 to 5/2/2019 08:30`)
2. If `Value` is repeated, and `Diff` is more than 0, copy the `Diff` in that row to `NewCol1` including the row after the last repeated `Value` with `Diff` more than 0 (example `5/2/2019 09:45 to 5/2/2019 10:30`)

Is pandas able to fully do the above conditions to this dataframe? If not, what other Python way can I try? Prefer to avoid `if else` as efficiently is important since there will be hundred thousands of rows.

Comment: Could you improve your question by following [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) to provide samples? Also, if `Value` is not repeated what the code is supposed to do, just copy `Diff`? And what if `Diff` is 0?

Answer (score 1):

Add column:

```
df['NewCol1'] = df['Diff']
```

---

I know, cause optimization  You want to avoid else if - but currently that solution can work:

between_ time - https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.between_time.html

apply - https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html

```
def convertValues(row):
    if (row['Diff'] > 0):
       return row['Diff']
    if (row['Diff'] == 0 and row['Date'].between_time('7:00','18:00'):
       return row['Value'] - int(row['Value'].name-1) / row.name
   
transformedDf = df.apply(lambda x: convertValues(x), axis=1)
```